# Decrypt password with salt using 3DES

Tags: java

I have a class named DESHelper that used to encrypt and decrypt password with a salt. Salt is username of that user. But this class still fail when it decrypt.

My class:

```
public class DESHelper {

    private String keyPass = "KeyPass";
    private String keyAlias = "keyAlias";
    private String keyStorePass="keyStorePass";
    private KeyStore ks = null;
    private static final String KEYSTORE_PATH = "keystore/mykeystore.keystore";
    private static final String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "jceks";    
    protected static String DES_KEY = "pin";
    private Map<String, byte[]> mKeys = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();

    public String decrypt(byte[] message, String salt) throws Exception {

        SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey();

        if (secretKey == null) 
        {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException("No secret key");
        }

        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(generateIV(keyAlias, salt, DES_KEY));
        final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);

        final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

        return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
    }

    public String encrypt(String value, String salt) {

        byte ciphertext[][] = new byte[2][];

        try
        {           
            SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey();

            if (secretKey == null) 
            {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("No secret key");
            }

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte iv[] = generateIV(keyAlias, salt, DES_KEY);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            ciphertext[0] = cipher.update(stringToByteArray(value));
            ciphertext[1] = cipher.doFinal(generateMAC(keyAlias, salt, DES_KEY, value));
        }
        catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) 
        {
            gse.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        if (ciphertext[0] == null) 
        {
            ciphertext[0] = new byte[0];
        }

        if (ciphertext[1] == null) 
        {
            ciphertext[1] = new byte[0];
        }

        byte ct[] = new byte[ciphertext[0].length + ciphertext[1].length];
        System.arraycopy(ciphertext[0], 0, ct, 0, ciphertext[0].length);
        System.arraycopy(ciphertext[1], 0, ct, ciphertext[0].length, ciphertext[1].length);

        // Convert encrypted bytes to a String
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * ct.length + 1);
        result.append("b");           // first byte indicates encoding method.
        Base64 enc = new Base64();
        result.append(enc.encode(ct));

        return result.toString();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
     */
    public SecretKey getSecretKey() throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, GeneralSecurityException{

        byte des_key[];
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede") ;

        if (secretKeyFactory == null) 
        {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException("No DESede factory");
        }

        try
        {
            des_key = getKey(keyAlias);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(des_key));

        return secretKey;
    }

    /**
     * Generate MAC
     */
    protected byte[] generateMAC(String type,String salt,String key,String value) {
        try 
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

            if (type!=null) {
                md.update(stringToByteArray(type));
            }

            if (salt!=null) {
                md.update(stringToByteArray(salt));
            }

            if (key!=null) {
                md.update(stringToByteArray(key));
            }

            if (value!=null) {
                md.update(stringToByteArray(value));
            }

            byte[] sha = md.digest();
            byte[] mac = new byte[4];

            for (int scan=0;scan<sha.length;scan++) 
            {
                mac[scan%4]=(byte)(mac[scan%4]^sha[scan]);
            }

            return mac;
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) 
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected byte[] generateIV(String type,String salt,String key) {
        try 
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

            if (type!=null) {
                md.update(stringToByteArray(type));
            }

            if (salt!=null) {
                md.update(stringToByteArray(salt));
            }

            if (key!=null) {
                md.update(stringToByteArray(key));
            }

            byte[] sha = md.digest();
            byte[] iv = new byte[8];

            for (int scan=0;scan<sha.length;scan++) 
            {
                iv[scan%8]=(byte)(iv[scan%8]^sha[scan]);
            }

            return iv;
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) 
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected byte[] getKey(String alias) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        synchronized (mKeys) 
        {
            byte k[] = mKeys.get(alias);
            if (k != null) {
                return k;
            }
        }

        byte key[] = getKeystoreKey(alias, 192);

        if (key == null) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (key.length != 24) {
            return null;
        }

        synchronized (mKeys) 
        {
            mKeys.put(alias, key);
            return key;
        }
    }

    protected byte[] stringToByteArray(String aString) {
        try 
        {
            return aString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } 
        catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Exception in stringToByteArray " + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Returns String From An Array Of Bytes
    */
    private String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i <= bytes.length; i++) 
        {
            stringBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
        }

        return stringBuffer.toString();

    }


    protected byte[] getKeystoreKey(String aKeyName,int size) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        Key key = getKeystore().getKey(aKeyName, keyPass.toCharArray());

        if (key==null) 
        {
            System.out.println("KeyStore key "+aKeyName+" not found");
            return null;
        }

        byte keyBytes[] = key.getEncoded();

        if (keyBytes.length != (size/8) ) 
        {
            System.out.println("KeyStore key "+aKeyName+" invalid length. Expected:"+size+" was: "+(keyBytes.length*8));
            return null;
        }

        return keyBytes;
    }

    protected KeyStore getKeystore() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        if ( ks == null )
        {
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE);
            char[] password = keyStorePass.toCharArray();

            if (password == null) 
            {
                System.out.println("Couldn't get keystore password from config");
            }

            // get the keystore as a resource
            InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(KEYSTORE_PATH);

            try
            {
                ks.load(is, password);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (is != null)
                {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }

        return ks;
    }

    public class Base64 {
        private char sBase64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".toCharArray();

        /** Creates a new instance of Base64 */
        public Base64()
        {
        }

        public byte[] decode(String aSource)
        {
            int aSource_length=aSource.length();

            while (aSource_length>0 && aSource.charAt(aSource_length-1)=='=') aSource_length--;

            if (aSource_length%4==1) 
            {
                return null;
            }

            int len = (aSource_length/4)*3 + aSource_length%4 - (aSource_length%4==0?0:1);
            byte result[] = new byte[len];

            int o_ofs=0;
            int i_ofs=0;

            while (i_ofs<aSource_length) 
            {
                int i24=0;
                for (int bscan=0;bscan<4;bscan++) 
                {
                    if (i_ofs<aSource_length) 
                    {
                        int decode = decode(aSource.charAt(i_ofs));
                        if (decode==-1) return null;
                        i24=(i24<<6)+decode;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        i24=i24<<6;
                    }

                    i_ofs++;
                }

                if (o_ofs<len) 
                {
                    result[o_ofs++]=(byte)(i24>>16);
                }

                if (o_ofs<len) 
                {
                    result[o_ofs++]=(byte)(i24>>8);
                }

                if (o_ofs<len) 
                {
                    result[o_ofs++]=(byte)(i24);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private int decode(char c)
        {
            if (c>='A' && c<='Z') 
            {
                return c-'A';
            }

            if (c>='a' && c<='z') 
            {
                return c-'a'+26;
            }

            if (c>='0' && c<='9') 
            {
                return c-'0'+52;
            }

            if (c=='+') 
            {
                return 62;
            }

            if (c=='/') 
            {
                return 63;
            }

            return -1;
        }

        public String encode(byte[] aSource)
        {
            int result_length = aSource.length*4/3 + (aSource.length%3==0?0:1);

            char result[]=new char[ ((aSource.length+2)/3)*4 ];

            int o_ofs=0;
            int i_ofs=0;

            while (i_ofs<aSource.length) {

                int i24=0;
                for (int bscan=0;bscan<3;bscan++) {
                    if (i_ofs>=aSource.length) {
                        i24=i24<<8;
                    } 
                    else {
                        i24=(i24<<8)+(aSource[i_ofs]&0xff);
                    }

                    i_ofs++;
                }

                if (o_ofs<result_length) result[o_ofs++]=sBase64[(i24>>18)&63];
                if (o_ofs<result_length) result[o_ofs++]=sBase64[(i24>>12)&63];
                if (o_ofs<result_length) result[o_ofs++]=sBase64[(i24>>6)&63];
                if (o_ofs<result_length) result[o_ofs++]=sBase64[(i24)&63];
            }
            while (o_ofs<result.length) result[o_ofs++]='=';
            return new String(result);
        }
    }

}
```

I got exception:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

at line:

```
final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);
```

in decrypt method.

My test method:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        DESHelper des = new DESHelper();
        String encryptedStr = des.encrypt("admin", "admin");
        DESHelper.Base64 base64 = des.new Base64();

        System.out.println("Encrypted String: " + encryptedStr);            
        System.out.println("Decrypted String"   + des.decrypt(encryptedStr.getBytes(), "admin"));

    }
```

Maybe I missing something? Correct me if I have something wrong. Thanks

Comment: You don't show where you call `decrypt()`, but obviously the length of the encrypted message is not a multiple of 8 bytes.  Anyway, it might help if we had a broader idea of what you're trying to accomplish with this.  If it's storing the passwords of your users in a database, you shouldn't be _encrypting_ the passwords but [hashing them](http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html).

Comment: You shouldn't be encrypting passwords in the first place, you should be digesting or hashing them. There are very important legal consequences of what you are doing, namely that you lose non-repudiability of transactions.

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks for your reply. Could you tell me where is the first place and what I should digesting or hashing first?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch, but try padding your input with binary zeroes to make it have a length divisible by 8.

Comment: I remove the first 'b' character and I did't get that Exception anymore and I decode by using base64 before decrypt:         System.out.println("Decrypted String"   + des.decrypt(base64.decode(encryptedStr.substring(1)), username));
But the final result is not as expected :( :( :(

Answer (score 0):

Block ciphers need that the input (for decrypting) has a proper length (padded).

This kind of errors can be avoided using the more convenient `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream` classes.